# Reflective material in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

How can I create a material that reflects other shapes from the scene? I have tried the `reflectivity` property but it didn't reflect anything.

[There is an example that seems to have this effect](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_shading_physical)

It doesn't look like standard materials were used to create this.

Comment: There are many, many examples of this: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cars_camaro, http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap, http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap_balls_reflection

Comment: If you want a mirror, there is an example of that, too: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_mirror

Comment: @WestLangley All of the examples except the mirror use an environment image for reflection. If you look closely at the material, you will see the image that was used. I specifically asked about reflecting other objects in the scene. The mirror example is good reference, thanks.

Comment: See http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic and http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic2

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To go into a bit of the theory: a reflection is basically an image of the scene taken from a certain position. So if you want a planar mesh to serve as a mirror, you'll have to add a camera at that position, have it render the scene to a texture in the animation loop, and then use that texture in the material for the planar mesh. I would also recommend looking at http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Reflection.html in addition to the examples WestLangley mentioned.

Also, play around with settings; for a less reflective effect, for example, try:

```
var mirrorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x111111, envMap: mirrorCamera.renderTarget } );
```

or

```
var mirrorMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { emissive: 0x111111, envMap: mirrorCamera.renderTarget } );
```

Comment: Thanks for yor answer. Im looking for reflective material for a floor object. The reflectivity has to come from objects in the scene. I havent seen any exampes of the desired effect. Something like a shiny plastic or metal. The reflection will be there that is a bit diffused, not like the mirror example. Although the mirror example is the closest example Ive seen. Can you pease provide some code to get me started?

Comment: Try changing the material parameters for the object that has the reflection, that will make it less reflective and may give it more of the desired effect. See updated answer above.

Answer (score 4):

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap
I did it with the above example:

```
new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial ({
    map: texture,    
    envMap: scene.background,      
    combine: THREE.MixOperation,     
    reflectivity: .5     
})
```

The key variable, as i understand, is THREE.MixOperation